# List View displays only empty rows. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Am trying to bind an sqlite datatable to a list view. Problem is it displays the correct number of rows in database but as empty rows. So if data count is five it displays five empty datarows. Below is the code to my whole solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.Properties;

namespace WpfApplication_tutorial.Model
{
    public class Student : IDataErrorInfo
    {

        public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;            
        }

        private Student() { }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

        string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
        {
            get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (string property in ValidatedProperties)
                    if (GetValidationError(property) != null)
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
        }

        static readonly string[] ValidatedProperties = 
       {
           "FirstName",
           "LastName"
       };

        string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
        {
            if (Array.IndexOf(ValidatedProperties, propertyName) < 0)
                return null;

            string error = null;

            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "FirstName":
                    error = this.ValidateFirstName();
                    break;

                case "LastName":
                    error = this.ValidateLastName();
                    break;

                default:
                    Debug.Fail("Unknown property being validated on Student", propertyName);
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }

        string ValidateFirstName()
        {
            if (IsStringMissing(this.FirstName))
            {
                return Strings.Student_MissingFirstName_Error;
            }
            return null;
        }

        string ValidateLastName()
        {
            if (IsStringMissing(this.LastName))
            {
                return Strings.Student_MissingLastName_Error;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static bool IsStringMissing(string value)
        {
            return
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim() == String.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

And below is the code to my viewmodel. It includes the fuction to create and select from table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.Model;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.View;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.UserControls;

namespace WpfApplication_tutorial.ViewModel
{
    public class StudentViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        readonly Student _student;
        private string firstName = string.Empty;
        private string lastName = string.Empty;
        private DataView studentDetails = null;


        // Command for registering new student
        private ICommand registerStudent;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the StudentViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public StudentViewModel()
        {
            _student = new Student(firstName, lastName);
            firstName = _student.FirstName;
            lastName = _student.LastName;
            FormOne();

        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _student.FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _student.FirstName)
                    return;
                _student.FirstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }




///Please note that i tried this to
       public string FirstName
        {
           get { return firstNam; }
           set 
           { 
              firstName = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
           }
       }


        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _student.LastName; }
            set
            {
                if (value==_student.LastName)
                    return;
                _student.LastName = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public DataView StudentDetails
        {
            get { return studentDetails; }
            set
            {
                if (value == studentDetails)
                    return;
                studentDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StudentDetails");
            }
        }


        public ICommand RegisterStudent
        {
            get
            {
                if (registerStudent == null)
                {
                    registerStudent = new CommandBase(i => this.CreateStudent(), null);
                }
                return registerStudent;
            }
        }

public void FormOne()
        {

            string databaseName = "Kwega.db3";
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseName + "; Version=3;");
            string students = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(students, connection);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "students");
            StudentDetails = ds.Tables["students"].DefaultView;
            connection.Close();

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method to create new student and creating a new student table if
        /// it doesnt exist in the database
        /// </summary>
        private void CreateStudent()
        {
            if (_student.IsValid)
            {
                string databaseName = "Kwega.db3";
                var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseName + "; Version=3;");
                connection.Open();
                var createStudentTable =
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name TEXT(255), last_name TEXT(255))";

                var createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(createStudentTable, connection);
                createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string insert_student = "INSERT INTO students(first_name, last_name) VALUES (" +
                                        "'" + _student.FirstName + "', '" + _student.LastName + "')";

                var insert_CMD = new SQLiteCommand(insert_student, connection);
                insert_CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student details weren't saved", "Invalid student!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }

        }

        string IDataErrorInfo.Error
        {
            get { return (_student as IDataErrorInfo).Error; }
        }

        string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string error = (_student as IDataErrorInfo)[propertyName];
                return error;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I think the error might be in my viewmodel but i just cant call it for the last 3 days. Below is my codebehind file and xaml file.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.Model;
using WpfApplication_tutorial.ViewModel;

namespace WpfApplication_tutorial.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FormOneDataControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FormOneDataControl : UserControl
    {        
        public StudentViewModel ViewModel;

        public FormOneDataControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                    
            StudentViewModel studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();            
            this.DataContext = studentViewModel;
        }  
     }
}
```

And finally my xaml file

```
<ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding }" DataContext="{Binding StudentDetails}" >
           <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"  />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

Please note that i tried using `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MethodName}" and`DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

A `DataView` is not a good container for your data. You'd be better off declaring a custom class with properties to display in your `ListView` so that you can use those named properties to data bind to.

At the moment, your XAML is mixed up... your `ListView` is looking in the `StudentDetails` property for items and that is a `DataView`, but then your `GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding`s are pointing to properties in your `StudentViewModel` which have no relation to the items in the `DataView`.

Instead, create a custom class with those name properties, then create a collection of that type in your `StudentViewModel` class and data bind to that collection property. Then your `GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding`s should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of this from a different angle.

Your ViewModel should contain a collection of Students, as opposed to 1 student per ViewModel.

```
public class Student
{
    //Student memebers here
}

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        this.Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        //Call some method to load all students into the collection.
    }

    ...
}
```

Then on your view, you can create an instance of the ViewModel, and bind to the Students collection. Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <YourNamespace:StudentViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Don't forget you will need to define the namespace of your ViewModel in the xmlns declarations at the top of the XAML view. The implementation on the view is just an example of how you can achieve the binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the the DataContext property of the control that contain  this ListView you already have your viewmodel class instance in the DataContext of the ListView, so is not necessary set that property. Try this:

```
<ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails}">
```

This page could help you understand better how data binding works:
[Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

It might help if you change the class Student like this way:

```
 public class Student : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    private Student()
    {
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == FirstName)
                return;
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == lastName)
                return;
           lastName = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    //...
}
```

So, in you ViewModel class you can have two properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentDetails {get;set;}
public Student SelectedStudent {get;set;}
```

And in the listview you can do something like this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
<YourNamespace:StudentViewModel x:Key="StudentViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource StudentViewModel}">
    <ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Anyway, I sugest use one of the framework created to apply this pattern in Silverlight, WPF, Windows Phone, Windows 8 and Xamarin Android app, for example [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)

Answer (score 0):

While there are some good answers already that will solve the problem of the moment, you have a conceptual error that I think is at the heart of your confusion. Namely, you are using StudentViewModel for two different kinds of model and they are in conflict. Each answer is choosing one of those models to be the primary and attempting to alter your code to give it primacy. I think the better choice would be to slightly alter the StudentViewModel to make the primary model clearer.

To me, it looks like you primarily conceive StudentViewModel to be a model of the Student rather than of the collection of students you'll eventually need to bind to your ListView. If that is the case, then you need to remove StudentDetails from the ViewModel and provide a static method for getting a list of valid StudentViewModel objects based on those in the database. This more clearly describes your intent with the StudentViewModel and makes it clear that the student details isn't a part of the class itself (because it can be called without instantiating the class). So StudentViewModel would look like this:

```
public class StudentViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    readonly Student _student;

    // Command for registering new student
    private ICommand registerStudent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the StudentViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public StudentViewModel(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        _student = new Student(firstName, lastName);
   }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _student.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _student.FirstName)
                return;
            _student.FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _student.LastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value==_student.LastName)
                return;
            _student.LastName = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public ICommand RegisterStudent
    {
        get
        {
            if (registerStudent == null)
            {
                registerStudent = new CommandBase(i => this.CreateStudent(), null);
            }
            return registerStudent;
        }
    }

public static IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> GetStudents()
    {

        string databaseName = "Kwega.db3";
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseName + "; Version=3;");
        string students = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students";
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(students, connection);
        connection.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "students");
        foreach (var student in ds.Tables["students"].DefaultView)
        {
            yield return new StudentViewModel(student[0], student[1]) // or whatever the fields actually are in the table
        }
        connection.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to create new student and creating a new student table if
    /// it doesnt exist in the database
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateStudent()
    {
        if (_student.IsValid)
        {
            string databaseName = "Kwega.db3";
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseName + "; Version=3;");
            connection.Open();
            var createStudentTable =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name TEXT(255), last_name TEXT(255))";

            var createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(createStudentTable, connection);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string insert_student = "INSERT INTO students(first_name, last_name) VALUES (" +
                                    "'" + _student.FirstName + "', '" + _student.LastName + "')";

            var insert_CMD = new SQLiteCommand(insert_student, connection);
            insert_CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student details weren't saved", "Invalid student!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }

    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return (_student as IDataErrorInfo).Error; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = (_student as IDataErrorInfo)[propertyName];
            return error;
        }
    }

}
```

I'd actually be more comfortable with it if you used an ObservableCollection rather than IEnumerable, but that's just me.

From there, you'd need a CollectionViewSource on your form and populate it with GetStudents.

```
public partial class FormOneDataControl : UserControl
{        
    public StudentViewModel ViewModel;

    public FormOneDataControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCollectionViewSource.DataSource = StudentViewModel.GetStudents(); // or myCollectionViewSource.ItemsSource? Crap, can't pull the CollectionViewSource properties from raw memory...
    }  
 }
```